# <ui-view> not displaying my templates

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm working on my first AngularJS project and have become puzzled as to why my templates are not displaying.  I doubt my checkpoint failed to cover something. However, I've resorted to copying and pasting their instructions and still cannot get my templates to display.

**Index.html** ( here)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="blocJams"> <!-- ng-app activates angular blocJams module (found in scripts/app.js) -->
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Bloc Jams Angular</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,800,600,700,300"> <!-- CDN -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles/landing.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles/collection.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles/album.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles/player_bar.css">
</head>
<body>
  <nav class="navbar"> <!-- navigation bar -->
      <a href="index.html" class="logo">
          <img src="assets/images/bloc_jams_logo.png" alt="bloc jams logo">
      </a>
      <div class="links-container">
          <a href="collection.html" class="navbar-link">collection</a>
      </div>
  </nav>

  <ui-view></ui-view>
//    also tried <div ui-view></div> too


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script> <!-- angulars source script -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.15/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script> <!-- UI Router Source -->
    <script src="/scripts/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**app.js** (module)

```
(function() {
    function config($stateProvider, $locationProvider) {
      $locationProvider
        .html5Mode({
            enabled: true,
            requireBase: false
        });

      $stateProvider
        .state('landing', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: '/templates/landing.html'
        });
        .state('album', {
            url: '/album',
            templateUrl: '/templates/album.html'
    }


    angular
        .module('blocJams', ['ui.router'])
        .config(config);
})();
```

**landing.html** (1 of 3 templates)

```
<section class="hero-content">
  <h1 class="hero-title">Turn the music up!</h1>
</section>

<section class="selling-points container clearfix">
  <div class="point column third">
    <span class="ion-music-note"></span>
    <h5 class="point-title">Choose Your Music</h5>
    <p class="point-description">The world is full of music; why should you have to listen to music that someone else chose?</p>
  </div>
  <div class="point column third">
    <span class="ion-radio-waves"></span>
    <h5 class="point-title">Unlimited, streaming, ad-free</h5>
    <p class="point-description">No arbitrary limits.  No distractions</p>
  </div>
  <div class="point column third">
    <span class="ion-iphone"></span>
    <h5 class="point-title">Mobile enables</h5>
    <p class="point-description">Listen to your music on the go.  This streaming service is available on all mobile platforms</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Curious as to what I am doing wrong and why my `<ui-view> directive` isn't displaying content with localhost:3000.  I don't show any errors when inspecting the elements.

**Further troubleshooting**

When I comment out `$stateProvider` from config function, the $locationProviders `.html5Mode` is coming back as `app.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'html5Mode' of undefined`.  Or if I comment out `$locationProviders` and leave `$stateProvider` I get `app.js:12 Uncaught TypeError: $stateProvider.state is not a function`.  Thanks

Comment: what error you are getting ?

Comment: Change the "landing" state URL to `''` (empty string)

Comment: Did you try to comment the html5 options, maybe that's the problem

Comment: @Phil changed URL to an empty string and still is not displaying templates.  @Paulo I tried commenting out this option already and also not displaying my templates.  When in my module should the templates be displayed?  When I route `.state?`

Comment: Re-opened. Please update the code in your question

Comment: I solved my problem through hit and miss troubleshooting.  However, I am still confused how I was suppose to navigate to my solution with the errors that prompted (as updated above).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow all of my above code was correct and my problem was found from a typo within my `main.css` folder:

```
body {
        background-image: url(..assets/images/blurred_backgrounds/blur_bg_3.jpg);
...
    }
```

and changed `assets/...` to `/assets/..`

```
body {
        background-image: url(../assets/images/blurred_backgrounds/blur_bg_3.jpg);
...
    }
```

No clue as to why it did not prompt an error while inspecting, otherwise I would of posted it above.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have given your landing page url as **/** . To make a default route you should inject **$urlRouterProvider** into your config function and set default route as below

```
(function() {
    function config($stateProvider, $locationProvider,$urlRouterProvider) {
      $locationProvider
        .html5Mode({
            enabled: true,
            requireBase: false
        });
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
      $stateProvider
        .state('landing', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: '/templates/landing.html'
        });
        .state('album', {
            url: '/album',
            templateUrl: '/templates/album.html'
    }


    angular
        .module('blocJams', ['ui.router'])
        .config(config);
})();
```

Comment: I tried this and injecting did not work in this situation.